Balanced cocircuit cover
Are there studies on matroids which can be covered by $r$ cocircuits ($r$ is the rank of the matroid), so each element is covered by a small number of times?
For example, it is known graphic matroids have this property. Consider the set of edges around each vertex, except one, which would cover all edges at most twice.
